# Keycloak is returning: Invalid parameter: redirect_uri

Tags: keycloak

Keycloak (19.0.1) is running in a server (with docker) external with a domain and tests are beeing realized from another network, i found the problem could be http://localhost:8080, but I have another system with Auth0 that works with http://localhost:8080.

Code:

```
let initOptions = {
  url: 'https://keycloakaddr.example.com', realm: 'myrealm', clientId: 'myrealm', onLoad:'login-required'
}
```

Joining in http://localhost:8080, redirects to https://keycloakaddr.example.com but with the return:
`Invalid parameter: redirect_uri`

Some images:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Third image is my problem... I'm getting: Invalid parameter: redirect_uri

Comment: So then what *is* the redirect URI?

Comment: @DanielB: http://localhost:8080, like image 1.

Comment: It most certainly isn't. Im referring to the actual value as present in the query string.

Comment: https://keycloakaddr.example.com/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=myrealm&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&state=662f94c9-a3c3-4473-a318-9cba7be766d8&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=bdcfdbcc-03bd-4c89-8a2d-e397c827611c

Comment: I achieved! The problem was in the clientId, I was creating the client into the master realm, and not into the realm I was wanting to test.